# How to intersect two arrays and keep the key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ecmascript-6

In PHP we have a method called `array_intersect`:

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

So it would be something like this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

The output:

> Array (
>       [a] => green
>       [0] => red )

As you can see it keeps the keys `a` and `0`.

I know that arrays in JavaScript is different from PHP but they are similar to an object in JavaScript.

Imagine that I have this input:

```
let a = ['my', 'life', 'sucks', 'so', 'hard'];
let b = ['life', 'sucks', 'hard'];
```

I wanted this to result in something like this:

> let r = { 1: 'life', 2: 'sucks', 4: 'hard' }

In resume, the keys would be the index (position) that it has been found.

I saw a method that was created with ES6 that is something like this:

```
const intersect = (leftArray, rightArray) => leftArray.filter(value => rightArray.indexOf(value) > -1);
```

But again, it won't return the keys only the value that has been found.

And if is possible to create using ES6 as well cause I think that the syntax is much cleaner.

Comment: the array values are gold. upvoted.

Comment: ['my', 'life', 'sucks', 'so', 'hard'] === true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map the wanted properties.

```js
var a = ['my', 'life', 'sucks', 'so', 'hard'],
    b = ['life', 'sucks', 'hard'],
    result = Object.assign(...a.map((v, i) => b.includes(v) && { [i]: v }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution with [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let a = ['your', 'life', 'sucks', 'so', 'hard'];
let b = ['life', 'sucks', 'hard'];

let r = a.reduce((obj, item, index) => {

  if(b.includes(item)) {
     obj[index] = item;
  }
  
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(r);
```